# iPad 3 come now. I should re-write my code for new screen size or iOS scale it automatically?

Tags: ipad, size, screen, retina-display

Now I use Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5.0. And developing for iPad 1st generation. In my application I use hardcoded sizes - 1024x768. I'm worry how my app will be look in new retina screen!?. Each time for the view.frame I use - CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

I know I should use 2x images. But my question is different. How about my hardcoded x/y position for some UIViews?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to change the coordinates and sizes in your code. Just add the @2x images. The same things that apply for the retina display of the iPhone apply to the new iPad.

Comment: My question was different. I know about @2x images. Not sure how to explain... For example if I created UIImageView with size.width = 1024 pixels and size.height = 768. Then on iPad 3 this image will be fullscreen ? or it will be only part of the image on the screen? Because retina display have 2048 x 1536 size.

Comment: @user1195202 - As I said, you don't have to change the coordinates and sizes in your code. The frame of the window will remain 768x1024. So don't change the size of your `UIImage`.